# Remove child image from RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have a set of images in a RelativeLayout, and I'd like to programmatically remove some of them. Is there some kind of metadata property (ie ID, tag etc) that I can assign these images (when adding them to the layout), so that I can easily find and them remove them?

Scenario: As a learning tool I am making a tower defence game. As a unit is killed, I want to remove its image. There are ~20 other units/images in the layout at the time.

thanks

Comment: are you using imageview for images?

Comment: while you are adding your views, use setTag property and assign unique value to your views & to access them back , use findViewWithTag to access the particular view

Comment: Yes. Using imageviews. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// remove all imageview from layout

```
               for (int pos = 0; pos < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); pos++)                            {
                if (relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos) instanceof ImageView) {
                    relativeLayout.removeView(relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos));
                }
```

// remove imageview by tag from layout

//set Tag to imageview

```
          imageview.setTag("yourimagetag");
```

//get imageview tag  and remove

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < relativeLayout.getChildCount(); pos++)              
  {                                                                    
    Object tag = relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos).getTag();
    if (tag != null && tag.toString().equals("yourimagetag")) {
    relativeLayout.removeView(relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos));
  }
```

Comment: its better to check `"yourimagetag".equals(relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos).getTag())` because it's possible to tag be null, so your code crashed in that line. you can even use `TextUtils.equals()`.

Comment: use This                                               relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos).getTag()!=null  && 
 relativeLayout.getChildAt(pos).getTag().equals("yourimagetag")             
   in if condition

Answer (score 1):

As i faced the same situation in one of project..

I stored all images in one array and assign tag to all imageview and then when to remove the imageview.first of all remove it from array and again load whole your array again to remove all views from that layout..

Hope you  may get help from this.